# Transfer data and schema from one database to another one table at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

Hope you all can help me out with this situation.  My boss built up a brand new database and he wants several of the old tables in the new database.  My question is how do I transfer the data and schema over from the old database to the new database without deleting the tables in the old database?  Here is my two databases: WTS-SQL-DEV = this is the old database
: WTS-Business = is the new database

*Additional info from comment:*

> I can access both databases on the same machine. I found a video on
>   youtube how to transfer the table over and the structure. I was
>   missing the data.

Comment: Oh Im running microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Take a full backup of old db. Copy to new computer.

Comment: If you have both databases on the same server or at least a linked server then inserting data like this would be a breeze. Let us know a bit more about this, can you access both databases from the same machine?

Comment: I can access both databases on the same machine.  I found a video on youtube how to transfer the table over and the structure.  I was missing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Two great answers already.

Another option is to right click the database, then go to Tasks > Export Data.

This will launch the import/export wizard.  You can define source/destination servers/databases and objects, and copy everything.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: I got the data through the importer/exporter.  That was easy.  Is there an easy way to included all the extra stuff like constraints and such?

Comment: Those would likely need to be scripted.  Right click DB > Tasks > Generate Scripts.  In "Set Scripting Options", click Advanced and near the bottom you can enable scripting of constraints/keys/indexes/triggers/etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a backup of the database

[image]

[image]

1. On the new machine restore the database

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the 2 databases are on the same machine, and that you figured out how to get the schema over

(I use `Tasks - Create Scripts` from the right-click context menu on the database, and generate the scripts by selecting the individual tables, and save to new query window.. then it's as simple as doing Use [new_db] on top of each created script, and the objects will be created in the new database, where [new_db] is your new database name.).

Since the tables have the same structure, to insert the data, once you create tables in new DB, it is an `insert select` statement. Enable `identity insert` if there is (as should be) an autogenerated primary key column. Insert the data. Then disable `identity insert`.

```
-- Note: Identity_Insert is required if there is an identity column present
-- Otherwise those two lines can be removed/commented out
Use [new_db]
Set IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] On 
Insert Into [table_name] 
-- Note 2: Default schema is [dbo], but technically, it is [db].[schema].[table]
Select * From [old_db].[dbo].[table_name]
Set IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] Off
```

Pretty straight-forward in your case, and no need to backup/restore the db. If the databases were on separate, non-linked servers, a backup/restore would be needed in order to get the old and new databases on the same machine... something that you already have in your particular case.

Comment: Use [WTS-Business]
Set IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[WTS-Expense-RecurringCharges] On 
Insert Into [dbo].[WTS-Expense-RecurringCharges] 
Select * From [WTS-SQL-DEV].[dbo].[WTS-Expense-RecurringCharges]
Set IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[WTS-Expense-RecurringCharges] Off  Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Reference to database and/or server name in 'WTS-SQL-DEV.dbo.WTS-Expense-RecurringCharges' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
I tried to follow your example this is what I see when I do excute

Comment: @kliebwatchtower This appears to be an SQL 2016 limitation (`cross database transaction` when two databases are on the same instance are not allowed... I think @JiggsJedi's answer may be the way to go here.